# BigQueryで単語検索を行いたい

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

BigQueryで開発を行っているのですが、性能、コストの件で悩んでいます。
お力を貸していただけないでしょうか？

**実現したいこと**
Thanks for your message about
などの英文を単語検索したい
forと検索したらforを含んだ情報のみ抽出したい
※fore,foreverなどは対象外

1. 案1
   　　`UNNEST(SPLIT(英文, ' ')) AS word`
   　　でSQL内で分割してからword = 'for'検索
2. 案2
   　　単語を予め配列化してDBのカラムに配列型として格納
   　　その配列型に対してUNNESTを使って分解してから'test'で検索

案1は実装は容易なのですが、性能面で不安を感じます。
案2はDBに格納するデータ量が増える事が懸念されます。

よろしくお願いします。